# Proving Inequality Of Squares and Roots

Tags: inequality

I've been working at trying to prove this. My gut says to use the AMGM since I see the inequality and there are lots of similar looking problems that use this. I've made a list of what I think might be potentially relevant and useful AMGM inequalities:

$$a^2b^2 +a^2c^2 + c^2b^2 \ge (a + b + c)abc $$
$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \ge 3(abc)^{2/3} $$
$$(\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2})(\frac1a + \frac1b + \frac1c) \ge 3\sqrt{3} $$

Then I went about trying my hand at various substitutions and trying to piece these together. You can see one page (of many) attached below. What am I missing?

[image: here.]

Comment: 1) The top line is missing a $"+"$ sign. 2) You are overcomplicating it, just write AM-GM for each of the three sums on the left-hand side.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3}}\geq\sqrt[3]{abc}$

$ab+ac+bc\geq3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}$

$a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2\geq3\sqrt[3]{a^4b^4c^4}$

Combine them.